# Selecting and displaying data from the last 5 entries in a table

Tags: php, mysql

So, after searching for a while here in stack overflow, I found a way of doing it:`

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM (SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5) sub ORDER BY id DESC";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    echo $row[0];`
```

However when I echo the $row[0] to get the first entry it doesn't display anything. I have checked my connection to the database and used the query on the phpmyAdmin and it worked fine, not sure why isn't it displaying the data (There is also a user in the table with the ID 1).

Comment: It should be `$row['username']` since you used `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Why do you have the subquery? Just `SELECT username FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5`

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array, not a numbered array. So the index of each column in the result is the column name, `$row['username']`.

If you want all 5 usernames, you need to call it in a loop. Each call just returns one row of the results, not all of them at once.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['username'] . '<br>';
}
```

To get a numbered array you use `mysqli_fetch_row()`. You still need the loop to get all of them.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo $row[0] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: How can I make it so it returns a numbered array? Thank you for your quick answers

Comment: Use `mysqli_fetch_row()` to get a numbered array. But you still need the loop to get all 5 names.

Comment: Actually, after trying, it still isn't displaying anything :/

Comment: I meant for you to put that inside the `while`, not after it's done. `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    var_dump($row);
}`

Comment: It's always `NULL` when the loop finishes, because that's what the `while` condition is checking for.

Comment: I fixed it, apparently the PHP version of the free web host  is kinda old so I went on and tried using mysql instead of mysqli functions and it worked perfectly with the query you suggested. Thank You so much for helping me, I am a 15 year old guy just trying to get by programming and when Im about to quit people like you show up and help me.By the way, I am currently developing my own browser game, if you want to check it out its dayone.coolpage.biz